# Java : Combobox Doesn't Display Selected Image

Tags: java, image, combobox, javafx

I'm trying to show a 2 Dimensional ComboBox-Array  (10 x 10)
and have it represent a board.
In each combobox i'm supose to select an image.
This works but the only problem is that it doesn't show the selected image.
Only for maybe 5 out of 10 comboboxes it shows the Select Image.
This has been bothering me for days and i can't find the solution.
This is what the code looks like.
Additional Information : ( It's inside a Gridpane and the picture at the bottom shows how it looks )

```
for(int i = 0;i<(comboboxarray.length)*8;i=i+8)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j<comboboxarray[i/8].length;j++)
        {
            ComboBox box = new ComboBox(objectenlist);
            box.setItems(objectenlist);
            box.setPrefSize(50, 50);
            box.getSelectionModel().select(1);
            box.setCellFactory(
        new Callback<ListView<ImageView>, ListCell<ImageView>>() 
        {
            @Override public ListCell<ImageView> call(ListView<ImageView> param) 
            {
                final ListCell<ImageView> cell = new ListCell<ImageView>() 
                {
                    {
                        super.setPrefWidth(USE_PREF_SIZE);
                    }    
                            @Override public void updateItem(ImageView item, 
                                boolean empty) 
                                    {
                                            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                                                        if (item != null) 
                                                        {

                                                            switch (item.getId()) {
                                                                case "MUUR":
                                                                    setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/gui/images/Muur.png"))));
                                                                    break;
                                                                case "EMPTY":
                                                                    setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/gui/images/empty.png"))));
                                                                    break;
                                                                case "DOEL":
                                                                    setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/gui/images/VELDDOEL.png"))));
                                                                    break;
                                                                case "VELD":
                                                                    setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/gui/images/VELD.png"))));
                                                                    break;
                                                                case "KIST":
                                                                    setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/gui/images/KIST.png"))));
                                                                    break;
                                                                case "START":
                                                                    setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/gui/images/START.png"))));
                                                                    break;
                                                            }

                                                        }else{
                                                            setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/gui/images/empty.png"))));

                                                        }
                                    }
                            };
                            return cell;
                        }
                    });
            comboboxarray[i/8][j] = box;

           add(comboboxarray[i/8][j],i , j, 8, 1);

        }
    }
```

![example][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the Java documentation of `ComboBox`:

> It is important to note that if a cell factory is set on a ComboBox,
>   cells will only be used in the ListView that shows when the ComboBox
>   is clicked. If you also want to customize the rendering of the
>   'button' area of the ComboBox, you can set a custom ListCell instance
>   in the button cell property.

In short, you also need to set `combobox.setButtonCell()`. However a better option is to use `ChoiceBox` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your golden advice.
Adding this Code solved it for me!

```
box.setButtonCell(new ListCell<ImageView>() 
            {
                    @Override protected void updateItem(ImageView item, boolean empty) 
                    {
                      super.updateItem(item, empty);
                      if (item == null || empty) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                      } else {
                        setGraphic(new ImageView(item.getImage()));
                      }
                    }
              });
```